# Applying distributive law for two strings in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am trying to apply the distributive law for two strings, e.g. "ab+ac" returns "a(b+c)". I managed to do that. But the problem I am facing is with longer texts. e.g. "aabbcd+aabbgf" it should return "aabb(cd+gf)".
Where is the problem in my code?

```
inputString = input("Enter Regular Expression: ")
def destributionOfAnExpression():
    if "+" not in inputString:
        return inputString
    else:
        h = inputString.split("+")
        y = h[0]
        z = h[1]
        similar = ""
        for i in y:
            for j in z:
                while i==j:
                    similar+=i
                    break
                break
        print(similar+"("+y.strip(similar)+"+"+z.strip(similar)+")")
```

Comment: Try the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) guide?

Comment: Your inner `for` loop stops after one iteration so it will only inspect the second string's first character

Comment: How can I prevent that?

Comment: I suggest you read through the link that Jiří Baum provided. There are a number of issues with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is here:

```
    for i in y:
        for j in z:
```

You *don't want* to compare *every* symbol in `y` with *every* symbol in `z` (Cartesian product), but to compare symbols *in sync*, i.e. *at the same position:*

```
    for i in range(min(len(y), len(z))):
        if y[i] == z[i]:
            similar += y[i]
        else:
            break
```

*Note:* No other `break` in your code.

---

The second issue consists in applying the `.strip()` method, which strips given substring from *both* ends of the string, which is error-prone.

Use `.lstrip()` ("left" strip) instead, or – even better – use `y[i+1:]` and `z[i+1:0]`:

```
 print(similar + "(" + y[i+1:] + "+" + z[i+1:] +")")
```

But concatenating more than two strings with `+` is horrible – use [f-string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) instead:

```
first  = y[i+1:]
second = z[i+1:]

print(f"{similar}({first}+{second})")
```

---

Some notes:

1. It is not a good practice to use a variable (`inputString`) from the global scope in the body of your function. Provide it as a parameter:

   ```
   def destributionOfAnExpression(inputString):
   ```
2. It is not a good practice to print the result in the body of the function. Return it instead:

   ```
   return f"{similar}({first}+{second})"
   ```

   Users of your function may decide themselves, if they want to print it, or use it in other way.
3. Names of your variables are important. `y` or `z` describe nothing, `similar` is confusing – what about `common` instead?
4. Instead of

   ```
   h = inputString.split("+")
   y = h[0]
   z = h[1]
   ```

   you may use

   ```
   y, z = inputString.split("+")         # so called "unpacking" list (or tuple)
   ```
5. Your prompt "Enter Regular Expression: " is confusing. You don't expect a *regular* expression, but an *algebraic* expression, do you?
6. Use names in concordance with [PEP 8 – Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names), i.e. not

   ```
   destributionOfAnExpression
   ```

   but

   ```
   distribution_of_an_expression
   ```

   (all lowercase, the underscore as a word delimiter, a.k.a "snake_case").

Comment: About point 5, the whole project is about algebraic laws for regular expressions and this is only one function in it. But overall the notes you wrote are very helpful, and I really appreciate the time you spent writing them.

Answer (score 0):

change the while loop for an if statement and remove the last break

```
def destributionOfAnExpression(inputString):
    if "+" not in inputString:
        return None
    else:
        h = inputString.split("+")
        y = h[0]
        z = h[1]
        similar = ''

        for i in y:
            for j in z:
                if i == j:
                    similar += i
                    break

        print(similar+"("+y.strip(similar)+"+"+z.strip(similar)+")")
```

I also made some changes to your function that should prevent future errors

Comment: By the way, using strip will remove the entirety of an occurence. When you pass "aaab+aaz"  you'll get aaa(b+z) when you should get aa(ab + z)